# ElementTree does not seem to get some texts/elements in the tree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.7

I have a wikipedia dump that I want to parse, and I am having some difficulties/mysterious problems while using Python xml parser, ElementTree.

My recent problem is, ElementTree does not seem to find the texts that are actually there. This is an example data:

```
<page>
    <title>Cengiz Han</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>10</id>
    <revision>
      <id>20337884</id>
      <parentid>20218916</parentid>
      <timestamp>2019-01-29T14:02:43Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>CommonsDelinker</username>
        <id>31545</id>
      </contributor>
      <comment>China_11b.jpg dosyası Map_of_China_1142.jpg ile değiştirildi</comment>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">
         ...some long Genghis Khan stuff...
      </text>
</page>
```

Now when I parse it with this:

```
for event, elem in et.iterparse('dataset/wiki_test', events=('start', 'end', 'start-ns', 'end-ns')):
    if event == 'start':
        if elem.tag == 'page':
            if len(list(elem)) == 0:
                continue
            title = elem.find('title').text
            if title == None or 'MediaWiki' in title:
                elem.clear()
                continue
            wiki_id = elem.find('id')
            if wiki_id == None:
                elem.clear()
                continue
            wiki_id = wiki_id.text
            revision = elem.find('revision')
            if revision != None:
                print(list(revision))
                text = revision.find('text').text
                print(text)
                if text != None:
                    count += 1
                    titles += title + '\n'
                    page = {'wiki_id': wiki_id, 'title': title, 'text': text.text}
                    pages += json.dumps(page, ensure_ascii=False) + '\n'
        elem.clear()
```

`revision.find('text').text` line seems to find no text for **some** elements, including the one above, and that some makes like one seventh of my data, which is annoying. This was also the case for page->id for some other entries, in which it claimed that element does not exist at all. I solved that problem by ignoring that ones, but I don't really want to do that, also this error does not make sense to me at all.

Here is another page, which works totally fine.

```
<page>
    <title>Mustafa Suphi</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>22</id>
    <revision>
      <id>20077185</id>
      <parentid>20017115</parentid>
      <timestamp>2018-10-14T08:31:32Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>Vikiçizer</username>
        <id>90501</id>
      </contributor>
      <comment>/* top */düzeltme  [[Vikipedi:AWB|AWB]] ile</comment>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text xml:space="preserve">
          ...some Mustafa Suphi stuff...
      </text>
      <sha1>m5finh6h2kr8h2fbtmsatp5fhz1siwq</sha1>
    </revision>
  </page>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `event == 'start'` does not guarantee that the whole Element are present. Change to `event == 'stop'`

Comment: Can you please upload a complete XML and explain what is the data structure you want to extract from this XML?

Answer (score 0):

You have posted two examples: "working" and "not working".

In the "not working" one there is no

`</revision>`

Are you sure this the XML you have or it is just copy & paste mistake.

Comment: Copy paste mistake.